# bash: Dynamic colorful prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, escape-sequences

I give my `git` colorful prompt but it never fully works. After so many trails I've pinned point where the problem is (completely stripped `git` out of the problem). Here it is, manifesting the symptom as simple as possible:

- Following up on [bash: Colorful prompt and long command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1565733/), I need to close escape sequences with `\]` in order for 'readline' to correctly calculate the prompt's visible length
- It works with `PS1` setting *statically*, but not *dynamically*:

```sh
     echo -e '\e[33m\]00\e[0m\]' | tee /tmp/p
     PS1="\n\w`cat /tmp/p`\\\$ "
     PS1='\n\w`cat /tmp/p`\\\$ '
     echo -e '\[\e[33m\]00\[\e[0m\]' | tee /tmp/p
```

[image]

Comment: Not an answer but you should look into using `tput` instead of direct escape sequences.  It *might very well help* your problem but for sure is better bash scripting.  See [this](https://linux.101hacks.com/ps1-examples/prompt-color-using-tput/)  for starters.

Comment: The question shows research effort and it's useful, but it's not as clear as it should be (and it's not really a question). It took me several minutes to *guess* what your exact goal may be, why you run these exact commands in this exact sequence, which parts are truly relevant, which parts worked as expected and which didn't. It would be much better if you explained each command: why did you run it? what did you expect from it? what aspect of the problem did you want to show us by it? This comment is a feedback, I did my best and answered regardless of the obstacle. I hope I guessed right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Bash(+readline) detects `\[` and `\]` in `PS1` before the command substitution (`` `cat /tmp/p` ``) is expanded. If `\[` or `\]` appear because of a substitution, it's too late for them to have the desired effect and they appear verbatim.

> It works with `PS1` setting statically, but not dynamically

Not quite. Formally `PS1` (the variable) is static in both cases. In case of double-quoted `` `cat /tmp/p` `` the variable contains the result of command substitution obtained once during the assignment. In case of single quoted `` `cat /tmp/p` `` the variable contains this literal string. In both cases the value of the variable is fixed after you assign it, it doesn't change automatically.

Still when the shell *interprets* the latter static value for the purpose of printing the prompt, it expands `` `cat /tmp/p` ``. So the prompt is indeed dynamic in this case, but not the variable.

The solution is to make the variable truly dynamic, i.e. to make something update its *value* each time just before the shell needs the variable. The value should contain the result from `` `cat /tmp/p` ``, so all `\[` and `\]` (including these from `/tmp/p`) are there when the shell starts interpreting the value.

This can be done with `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

> `PROMPT_COMMAND`
> If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt (`$PS1`).

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables))</sup>

Example:

```
echo -e '\[\e[33m\]00\[\e[0m\]' | tee /tmp/p      # taken from your code
update_PS1 () { PS1="\n\w`cat /tmp/p`\\\$ "; }
PROMPT_COMMAND=update_PS1
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil. _"I give my git colorful prompt but it never fully works. ... the problem is (completely stripped git out of the problem)"_. I.e., the `cat /tmp/p` part is to simulate the bash script of https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt, but bringing that into the discussion will only make the things ten times more convoluted.